# What are the types of classes/instances I can inject a CDI event into?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, cdi

I want to have a class that can fire an event. Ideally, I'd like to have it in a POJO (dealing with legacy code that's in POJOs) but I know that's not possible. So instead, I'd like to have something that the POJOs can call which can fire the event.

NOTE: I'm on Tomcat with CDI, JPA also installed *(It is not an option to switch to a full EE server on this project)*

I'm not sure if it should be a singleton/app-wide-singleton, or should be per request (or even session). So my questions are:

1. What can an event be injected into? (e.g. `@WebListener`, `@Singleton`, `RequestScoped`, `@Stateless`)
2. Which one makes the most sense for this use case?
3. how would a POJO get access to that class/instance (the POJO is called from a servlet)?

Sample Code:

```
//Is this correct?
@WebListener
public class EventHandler
{
    @Inject
    @MyEventQualifier
    private Event<MyEvent> myEvent;

    public void fireEvent(MyEvent anEvent)
    {
        myEvent.fireAsync( anEvent );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental container classes are your standard "managed" objects, like the one you listed (WebListeners, Filters, Servlets). These act as the root of the context chain. Since those are managed by CDI, anything that they Inject are also managed, and on down that line.

If your Servlet (for example) injects PojoX, PojoX can inject PojoY, and on and on. The game is to avoid `new` and use CDI constructs instead to create your POJOs.

As for hurdling the legacy POJO/CDI divide, you could do a couple of things.

You could inject an instance of `EventHandler` in to the Servlet, and then pass that instance in to the POJO as a parameter.

You can stick that instance in to the request as an attribute, or shove the instance in to the ServletContext when the Servlet is first created.

You can make EventHandler an `@Singleton` and in its `@PostConstruct` set a static variable that can be returned via a standard, static `getInstance` call.

You can have your POJO call the container directly to do the lookup (or call a utility function).

And, of course, if the POJO can be injected itself, just do it that way.

Addenda for the comment:

You can simply inject the POJO, if that's appropriate for you work.

Here's an example:

```
@WebServlet(name = "NewServlet", urlPatterns = {"/NewServlet"})
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    Instance<Pojo> pojoInstance;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Pojo pojo = pojoInstance.get();
        String world = pojo.getWorld();

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet NewServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("<p>Hello " + world);
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }
}

public class Pojo {

    @Inject
    Event<PojoEvent> pojoEventHdlr;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println("Look, another Pojo!");
    }

    public String getWorld() {
        PojoEvent pe = new PojoEvent("World event pojo fired");
        pojoEventHdlr.fire(pe);

        return "world";
    }
}

public class PojoEvent {

    String msg;

    public PojoEvent() {
    }

    public PojoEvent(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "PojoEvent with msg: " + msg;
    }
}

@Singleton
public class SingletonPojo {

    public void pojoEventObserver(@Observes PojoEvent pe) {
        System.out.println("We got a PojoEvent " + pe);
    }
}
```

The important thing to note, is that I injected an `Instance<Pojo>` in to the servlet, and then used `Instance.get` on it, rather than just the Pojo directly. The reason for that is Servlet are nominally Singletons within the web app, so if you injected an actual Pojo, all of your requests would use the exact same instance of the Pojo (unlikely what you want).

You can see the Pojo fires the event, and I have a `@Singleton` class observing the event and dumping out the message.

If you're willing to make changes to you legacy code, you can do what you like and there's no real need to jump through hoops to bridge the CDI <-> legacy divide. Just roll them in to CDI as necessary.

Comment: For the last one,  how would I inject the POJO? And if idid,  could ialso I inject the event my in to the POJO?